# Check if a value is defined in an C enum?

Tags: c, enums

Assuming that I have this:

`enum { A = 0x2E, B = 0x23, C = 0x40 }`

it's possible check if `x` is defined into `enum`?

I'm doing it manually: `int isdef = (x == A || x == B || x == C);` But I want to something more dynamic. `GCC-extensions` are welcome too.

Comment: no, you probably need to use something else like a set<>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is kind of a modified version of your question, but depending on what you're doing, something like this might work:

```
enum {A,B,C};
const int E[] = {0x2E,0x23,0x40};
// Or:
// enum { A = 0x2E, B = 0x23, C = 0x40 };
// const int E[] = {A,B,C};

int isEnum(int x)
{
    for(int i=0; i<(sizeof(E)/sizeof(*E)); i++)
    {
        if(E[i] == x){ return 1; }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Value of A: 0x%02x\n", E[A]);
    // Or:   
    // printf("Value of A: 0x%02x\n", A);

    printf("isEnum(0x2e): %s\n", isEnum(0x2e) ? "true" : "false");
    printf("isEnum(0x2f): %s\n", isEnum(0x2f) ? "true" : "false");
}
```

which outputs

```
Value of A: 0x2e
isEnum(0x2e): true
isEnum(0x2f): false
```

EDIT: TJD beat me to it, and his suggestion of using a sorted array and doing binary search would decrease your search time from *n* to log(*n*).

Comment: +1. I would also make x-macro to generate both enum and E[] - no need to manually synchronize between these two data structures.

Answer (score 13):

Not to the best of my knowledge. An enum in C is just a cleaner alternative to a series of

```
#define A 0x2E
```

statements.

If the enum is large and its values happen to be continuous, declare min/max constants and compare to those:

```
enum { E_MIN = 0x2E, A = 0x2E, B = 0x23, C = 0x40 ..., E_MAX=0x100};

if(x >= MIN && x <= MAX)
    ItsInEnum();
```

Comment: If values are discontinuous, you can put them in a constant array (sorted) and do a quick binary search to find if it's in there.

Comment: Since enums are compile-time constants, you could even design a perfect hash function and find the answer in *constant* time.

Comment: Hash calculation time might be comparable to that of comparison by hand. For enums, large-N behavior is not that relevant IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  `E_MIN` and `E_MAX` is a very good solution; but the values aren't continuos, so I can't use it.

Comment: Regarding your first statement, what is the equivalent of `#ifdef A` if `A` was defined in an enum?

Comment: There isn't one. Enum constants are identifiers, like variable and function names. If A is not defined and you try to use it, you'll get a compilation error. C doesn't easily admit checks for identifier validity.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to do this is:

---

```
enum {
    MODE_A,
    MODE_B,
    MODE_C
};

int modeValid(int mode)
{
    int valid = 0;

    switch(mode) {
        case MODE_A:
        case MODE_B:
        case MODE_C:
            valid = 1;
    };

    return valid;
}

void setMode(int mode)
{
    if (modeValid(mode)) {
        // Blah, blah
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    setMode(1);   // Okay
    setMode(500); // Error
}
```

Comment: K.I.S.S.: Keep It Simple Stupid. :)

Answer (score 8):

To expand on the accepted answer, use X-macros to build your enum and array from the same data using the preprocessor.

```
/* Only need to define values here. */
#define ENUM_VALUES \
    X(A, 0x2E)  \
    X(B, 0x23)  \
    X(C, 0x40)

/* Preprocessor builds enum for you */
#define X(a, b) a = b,
    enum {
        ENUM_VALUES
    };
#undef X

/* Preprocessor builds array for you */
#define X(a, b) a,
    const int E[] = {
        ENUM_VALUES
    };
#undef X

/* Copied from accepted answer */
int isEnum(int x)
{
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(E);i++)
    {
        if(E[i] == x){ return 1; }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't t be `(sizeof(E)/sizeof(*E))` instead of `sizeof(E)`?

Comment: @frarugi87, thanks, good catch! I see the part I copied from that other answer has since been edited to include the snippet you're referencing here.  Yes, you're right.

Comment: The X-macro that builds the array will result in `const int E[] = { A, B, C, };`. I think the macro should be `#define X(a, b) b, ` instead to give the desired `const int E[] = { 0x2E, 0x23, 0x40, };`.

Answer (score 1):

An `enum` is essentially the same thing as using macros to define constants, except that the `enum` wraps a set of associated constants up into a data type.  This makes your code more self-documenting, but doesn't really provide any additional functionality.

If you venture outside the realm of standard C, some compilers can do extra things with `enum` that they can't do with macros.  Some debuggers will map `enum` variables back to their name instead of showing their value.  Also, some compilers provide the ability to add run-time checks for things like out-of-bounds `enum` values.  This is essentially the same as the code you show, only the compiler adds it automatically.  With GreenHills' C compiler, this feature is enabled with the `-check=assignbound` compiler option.  I'm not sure if gcc has something like this built-in or not.  What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef enum {
  VALUE_1 = 0x01,
  VALUE_2 = 0x03,
  VALUE_3 = 0x0A
} values_e;

int main(void)
{
  int a = 0;
  values_e vlr;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &a);

    vlr = (values_e)a;
    switch (vlr) {
      case VALUE_1:
        printf("do ... value 1:\r\n");
        break;

      case VALUE_2:
        printf("do ... value 2:\r\n");
        break;

      case VALUE_3:
        printf("do ... value 3:\r\n");
        break;

      default:
        printf("ops...\r\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, it is not possible to check if an enum is defined by directly referring to an enum member.  However, there is a very simple shortcut: define a unique identifier associated with each enumerated type.  Then, when you want to check if an element of the enumeration exists, you can simply check if the associated identifier is defined:

```
//Header File:
typedef enum 
{
   ENUM_ELEMENT_1 = 0,
   ENUM_ELEMENT_2 = 1,
   ENUM_ELEMENT_3 = 2,
   ENUM_ELEMENT_MAX
} eEnumElement;

#define ENUM_ELEMENT_DEFINED  1
```

...

```
//Source file:
void TaskOperateOnEnums(void) 
{
   #if defined(ENUM_ELEMENT_DEFINED)
   eEnumElement Test = ENUM_ELEMENT_1;
   ...
   #endif
}
```