# How an enum is convert when it is out of index in C

Tags: c++, c, enums

In C++, I see

```
#include <iostream>

typedef enum {
    NORMAL = 0,
    EXTENDED
} CyclicPrefixType_t;

void func (CyclicPrefixType_t x) {
    if(x < NORMAL){
        printf ("lower\n");
    }else{
        printf ("higher\n");
    }
}

int main (void) {
    //MUST CAST OR WE GET ERROR
    CyclicPrefixType_t cpType = CyclicPrefixType_t(NORMAL - 1);

    func (cpType);
    return 0;
}
```

[Run the code on C++](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/xwsZZodI16)

Expected: `lower` > It is **OK**

But in C,

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
    NORMAL = 0,
    EXTENDED
} CyclicPrefixType_t;

void func (CyclicPrefixType_t x) {
    if(x < NORMAL){
        printf ("lower\n");
    }else{
        printf ("higher\n");
    }
}

int main (void) {
    //NO NEED TO CAST
    CyclicPrefixType_t cpType = (NORMAL - 1);

    func (cpType);
    return 0;
}
```

[Run the code on C](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/C05v44X1cT)

Actually Result: `Higher` >
It is **NOT OK**

In this case, (-1) is automatically cast to another value.
Anyone can tell me which value is here and how it is converted to
*Because if you print it(%d), It will still (-1)*

Comment: In C an `enum`'s underlying type could be unsigned. Can't remember if that's true in C++

Comment: @user4581301 In fact underlying type is implementation defined.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do that" --- "Don't do that, then".

Comment: Additionally, C and C++ are different languages, with different standards defining different behavior.

Comment: `if you print it, It will still (-1)` how did you print it? `printf` doesn't know the type of the argument so it's UB. You must use `std::cout` instead

Comment: When you decide the `enum` is `unsigned int` in c++. It will return high as well. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v1eY6zaxs)

Comment: `%d` assumes the stacked value given is a signed `int`, regardless of what you placed there or whether it is the right size. It believes that `%d` is the truth. The compiler, however, *might* issue a warning about mismatching types.

Comment: [C11 6.7.2.2p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2): *Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined, ...*

Comment: @user4581301: Re “Either way, assigning an unknown value to an `enum` is verboten”: [In both C and C++, an `enum` object may have values other than the named values.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68118192/when-is-the-compiler-allowed-to-optimize-away-a-validity-check-of-an-enum-or-enu/68118407#68118407) And assigning −1 to an `enum` is well defined subject to the selection of the underlying type. If it is a signed type, the assigned value is −1. If it is an unsigned type, it is wrapped.